# What, exactly IS the value of "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to catch the value of certain variable, and do something if it's null or undefined.

```
$(".change-engineer").change(function (e) {
    var prevContactID = $(this).data('prev-value');

    alert(prevContactID.value); // this shows "undefined"

    if (prevContactID.value === null)
    {
        // we never get here
    }

    if (prevContactID.value === "undefined")
    {
        // we never get here
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("ChangeProposalEngineer", "RequestForQuotes")',
        data: { "prevContactID": prevContactID },
        cache: false,
        complete: function (data) {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

On the server side, I can put a breakpoint on `ChangeProposalEngineer` and the value of `prevContactID` is "null".

But on the client side, this: `alert(prevContactID.value);` pops up with "undefined". But, I can't seem to figure out how to get inside an if-then when that value is null.

Comment: `undefined` is a special variable in javascript.  Try using it without any quotes.

Comment: `prevContactID.value === undefined` Simple!

Comment: `undefined` itself is a value. There is also the *variable* `undefined` that has the value `undefined`. `"undefined"` on the other hand is a string literal which produces a string value.

Comment: Also it is undefined because prevContactID is a string.  Strings do not have a property of 'value'.  They *ARE* values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't check for the string `"undefined"`. Check for [the primitive `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

```
if(prevContactID.value === undefined) {
    // we never get here
}
```

---

Alternatively, **check for [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in general**, which covers both `null` and `undefined`:

```
if(!prevContactID.value) {
    // we never get here
}
```

Comment: The second option makes the most sense for the code shown.

Comment: Third option, when the situation considers `null` and `undefined` to be functionally equivalent (fairly common), is to compare with `==` instead of `===`, because under `==` rules the values `null` and `undefined` are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Exact value of **undefined** is `undefined`.

```
if(prevContactID === undefined)
```

> undefined is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope. The initial value of undefined is the primitive value undefined.
>
> In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5 specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)**

Updated the answer after reading this comment

> Also it is undefined because prevContactID is a string. Strings do not have a property of 'value'. They ARE values. **Taplar**

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're strict comparing (===) with the string "undefined" instead of `undefined` as a literal. Undefined, by the way, is the same as absence of value. Whereas null is a value.

**EDIT** as suggested by Felix, undefined is a value too. Yes.. It would be better put if I said "undefined is the default value of variables that hasn't been defined yet, or hasn't been assigned any value).

Comment: *"Undefined, by the way, is the same as absense of value. Whereas null is a value."* [`undefined` is a value too](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-undefined-type). However, it is implicitly created in certain situations (such as access a non-existing property).

Comment: `undefined == "undefined"` evaluates to `false`,  even with a non-strict comparison.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are valid, but I think it's worth it to point out, comparing it to a string is completely fine. The only thing you're missing is a `typeof` prefixed before your comparison, consider the following

```
if(typeof prevContactID.value === "undefined") {

}
```

This would work.